# how to install my theme using wp quick install script?

Tags: wordpress, scripting, installation

i am using [WP Quick Install](http://wp-quick-install.com) Script to install WordPress and it works fine. but it's not installing my custom theme. i also placed theme as theme.zip in WP-quick-install folder but it shows a white blank screen on front-end.

what is wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you are using WP Quick Install in the first place?

I would simply suggest setting up the site as normal and adding your theme into the `/themes/` directory.

If this is daunting, just shout, but first read the [Wordpress Codex - Installing Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress)

Comment: dear friend i know this, but i also want to know about WP Quick Install Script. It tells that we can activate our own custom theme while installing through wp quick install script but it did not worked for me.